# Riemann sum of a function that is discontinuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I needed to find the upper Riemann sum of the following function over $[0,\pi/2]$:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
 \sin x & \text{when $x$ is rational} \\
 x      & \text{when $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}$$

I wanted a suitable partition to find the same.

Comment: Please re-write this.What is f(x) for irrational x? And over what part of the domain of f do you want the sum?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear what the function is when $x$ is irrational. But we still need to know the lower and upper limits for your Riemann sum.

Comment: I guess you want to compute these over a bounded interval ?

Comment: @Andre: Isn't an upper Riemann sum defined only over a bounded interval, with improper integrals defined as limits of the bounded integrals rather than as limits of finite sums?

Comment: @Andre Yes, it is for a bounded interval: [0,pi/2]. I made the changes in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $x>\sin x$ for positive $x$ and $x<\sin x$ for negative $x$.

If both the lower and upper bounds of integral are non-negative, choose every point in your partition to be irrational. This gives the "upper" values of the function in the interval, $x$. If the bounds themselves are rational, choose the second and next-to-last points in the partition (the ones next to the bounds) to be irrational and "close" to the bounds. E.g. if the partition has $n$ points, make those close-to-the-end points irrational and within $\frac 1n$ distanced from the endpoints. Then as $n\to\infty$ the first and last slices of the Riemann sum approach zero and are irrelevant to the greatest lower bound of the Riemann sums.

If both the lower and upper bounds of integral are non-positive, choose every point in your partition to be rational. This also gives the "upper" values of the function in the interval. If the bounds are irrational, do as in the previous paragraph.

If the lower bound is negative and the upper bound is positive, make the "middle" point of your partition to be zero. Then both the left halves and right halves will give the "upper values" for the overall sum.

The result of all these is that your partitions and resulting Riemann sums are finding the integral of $\hat f(x)=\max(\sin x,x)$ and give the same upper Riemann sums as $f(x)$.